# What is this thing here?

Tags: dodge, part-identification, abs

[image]

My rear abs locks up when it rains, Brake light is on. This part sits behind the driver headlight area.
I can't order the part unless we know what it is.
2002 Dodge Ram Van 2500.

Comment: Took it in to fix abs, they sent me this picture and a reference to the dodge house to fix it. Service guy doesnt even know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a connector that is not plugged into anything.  Presumably it is for an option that you don't have fitted to your car, hence it is not plugged into anything.

Why do you want to replace it?  Do you think it has something to do with the ABS fault?

Comment: Could also be a diagnostic port. Doesn’t look like OBD, though.

Comment: @BobCross  That is a possibility.

Comment: I would think it would have a cover if it was for an option that was not installed.  being open doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidWatson Some manufacturers may add a cover, but from my experience I would say that was the exception.  If there is nothing connected at either end of the cable, why would they waste money covering it?

Comment: @HandyHowie  OK, That makes sense.   I was assuming that one end of the harness was connected somewhere else.  Maybe like a foglight harness that ended up in the fusebox.

Comment: @DavidWatson it may well go back to the fuse box, but then you would find no relay or fuse where it connects to.

Comment: @Moab if you are asking the op, wouldn’t you be better adding your question under their question?